# Repo working with git submodules causeing eslint to look in the wrong dir

Tags: git, eslint, git-submodules, tsconfig, typescript-eslint

Started a new project and intended to use git sub-modules to separate server, client, and other resources into their own repos, while using a main repo to house the `dev.docker-compose-yaml`,  `docker-compose.yaml`, static site and other resources.

(This could be using sub-modules wrong so correct me if im wrong)

The project structure looks like this:

[image: proj_strut]

Client is react, server is Nest. Each contains their own `Dockerfile` which is built by `dev.docker.compose.yaml`. The app runs fine, but eslint is throwing an error:

```
Parsing error: Cannot read file 'c:\users\<user>\programing\projects\<thing>\tsconfig.json'. eslint [1, 1]
```

The correct path for the file its looking for is:

```
'c:\users\<user>\programing\projects\<thing>\**server**\tsconfig.json'
```

Is there a way to correct this? Should I not use sub-modules like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `tsconfigRootDir` to `.eslintrc.js` along with a test to make it work in a sub-module and stand alone.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  ...
  parserOptions: {
    ...
    tsconfigRootDir: fs.existsSync('../.gitmodules') ? '../server' : './', 
  },
};
```